# MYSQL HAVING WHERE not working

Tags: mysql, count, chat, aggregate, having

I have the following function

```
function availableChatRoom($topic_id){
$max_rooms = 2;
$max_users = 2;

$sqli = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT room_num) AS numRooms FROM forum_chat WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id'";
$num_rooms = queryColumnVal($sqli, "numRooms");

$sqlii = "SELECT room_num, COUNT(user_id) AS numUsers FROM forum_chat 
          WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id' AND (status = 'online' AND status = 'offline') AND chat_msg = ''
          GROUP BY room_num
          HAVING numUsers < $max_users ORDER BY msg_date";

$num_rooms_with_spaces = mysqlNumRows($sqlii, "room_num");
queryColumnVal($sqlii, "room_num");

if($num_rooms == 0){
    return 1;
}
elseif($num_rooms <= $max_rooms){

    if($num_rooms_with_spaces == 0){
        return $num_rooms + 1;
    }
    else{
        return queryColumnVal($sqlii, "room_num");
    }
}
else{
    return "none";
}
```

}

the idea is for the function to return a chat room number with space. 
 -Every time a user joins the room, a line with no msg is inserted with status online
 -Every time a user leaves the room a line with no msg is inserted with status offline
I am now trying to write a function which checks if there are any spare rooms for each topic
The idea is to select the room_num where the number of users who have logged in but not logged out is less than the maximum chatter per room.
Can someone help me with my $sqlii.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your query:

- `(status = 'online' AND status = 'offline')`

This asserts that your query wil return no now at all. Use: `(status = 'online' OR status = 'offline')` or the equivalent `(status IN ('online', 'offline'))`

- `COUNT(user_id)`

This does not count the difference of online minus offline users. Correct the logic.

- `ORDER BY msg_date`

In `GROUP BY` queries, it's not good to use non-aggregate column, at the `HAVING`, `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` clauses, despite that MySQL allows it. Unless that column depends on the grouping expression. Since `msg_date` obviously does not depend on `room_num`, you should replace that with an aggregate function:

`ORDER BY MAX(msg_date)`  or  `ORDER BY MIN(msg_date)`

---

```
$sqlii = "
   SELECT room_num, 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'online' THEN 1 END) 
            - COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'offline' THEN 1 END) 
          AS numUsers 
   FROM forum_chat 
   WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id' 
     AND status IN ('online', 'offline')
     AND chat_msg = ''
   GROUP BY room_num
   HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'online' THEN 1 END) 
          - COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'offline' THEN 1 END) 
          < $max_users 
   ORDER BY MAX(msg_date)
     ";
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be more complicated... works as i wanted. Any tips on where i can learn advanced queries like this? This is some serious stuff.

Comment: @JamesBondInBlack, Maybe http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/best-book-to-learn-mysql and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3740/suggest-a-mysql-book-for-me/3749#3749 ?

Answer (score 4):

The `HAVING clause` is **evaluated before the SELECT** - so the server doesn't yet know about that alias.

```
SELECT room_num, COUNT(user_id) AS numUsers 
FROM forum_chat 
WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id' AND 
      (status = 'online' OR status = 'offline') AND 
      chat_msg = ''
GROUP BY room_num
HAVING COUNT(user_id) < $max_users ORDER BY msg_date
```

1. First the product of all tables in the `from clause` is formed.
2. The `where clause` is then evaluated to eliminate rows that do not satisfy the search_condition.
3. Next, the rows are grouped using the columns in the `group by clause`.
4. Then, Groups that do not satisfy the search_condition in the `having clause` are eliminated.
5. Next, the expressions in the `select clause` target list are evaluated.
6. If the distinct keyword in present in the select clause, duplicate rows are now eliminated.
7. The union is taken after each sub-select is evaluated.
   8.Finally, the resulting rows are sorted according to the columns specified in the order by clause.

Comment: Actually, MySQL is a bit forgiving and allows aliases from the `SELECT` list to be used in `HAVING` clause. But that is definitely not in standard SQL.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, but it did not work. I tried this first because i understand the logic but thanks anyway

Comment: @ypercube, But practically all *real* DBs do allow that right?

Comment: @Pacerier No, some very real DBMS, (like Postgres, Oracle, SQL-Server) do not allow this. Check: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a5dc/1) As far as I know, only mysql and sqlite allow this non-standard syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the alias of the column in `HAVING` in the same `SELECT` level.
That is because in yout MySQL `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` would be activated.

Try this -

```
HAVING COUNT(user_id) < $max_users ORDER BY msg_date
```